# Could not load mysql.data on other computer

Tags: c#, mysql

I made a Winform application with C# and MySQL. its working perfectly on my computer, but when I publish it and run it on an other machine on the same network I get this error when I try a function with a MySQL query in it.

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.date, version=6.5.4.0, culture = neutral, publicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified

Do I need to instal MySQL on these computers or is there a another solution?

Comment: did you copy the required assemblies along with your application ?

Comment: @Nacereddine No I did not, don't know how either. could you explain it please?

Comment: you probably need to deploy the dll along wit the exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install MySQL server on every machine. Looks like the Assembly you're referencing was not found on the machine you deployed your application to.

In your solution explorer set the `Copy Local` property of your referenced MySQL assemblies to `true`

[image]

and when you deploy to other machines make sure to include the `MySQL.Data.dll` with your application.